# QGIS Map – Using OSM or Google as a baselayer, but make it searchable for places/cities too

Tags: openstreetmap, search

I am mapping specific points of interest in the Netherlands, using QGIS and a OSM layer. Obviously this is not searchable. In order to locate these 100 points of interest, I need to be able to find/search this OSM map rather than "visually" search on the map in order to locate the point I need to mark. Hope that makes sense. The addresses of the points of interest I have, are marked in an analogue PDF, so I have to go on Google find each of them to begin with and then do a visual search in QGIS, which is a bit cumbersome and I believe not necessary most likely.

Is there any tool or process I need to follow, in order to allow for a direct search of cities/places of the OSM layer?

Comment: The solution is: 

You need activate "Experimental plugins" and install "OSM place search" plugin.

In case anyone stumbles over this than the other question.